# Adding up total times a number was rolled on a dice in python 3

Tags: python, sum, dice

I have made a sided dice random generator , but i need for the programme to at the bottom print out
1 was rolled x amount of times
2 was rolled x amount of times
and so on.
how can I achieve this.

my code is :

```
import random
print("Six sided dice programme")
count = 1
while True:
    answer = str(input("would you like to roll, 'y' for yes, 'n' for no:"))
    if answer == 'y':
        roll=random.randint(1,6)
        print("roll number" , str(count) , ":" , roll)
        count = count + 1
    if answer == "n":
        print("Game over")
        break
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a tag for the programming language you use, it looks like `python`?

Answer (score 1):

You keep counts in an integer `count` variable. Change to a list/dict representing the count of each side of the dice.

#### list:

```py
import random

counts = [0] * 6
for i in range(10):
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("roll number" , i, ":" , roll)
    counts[roll-1] += 1

for side, count in enumerate(counts):
    print(side+1, "was rolled", count, "amount of times")
```

#### dict:

```py
import random
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(10):
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("roll number", i+1, ":", roll)
    counts[roll] += 1

for side, count in counts.items():
    print(side, "was rolled", count, "amount of times")
```

<sup>* this will print the counts in order of the first appearance of each side</sup>